# How to display details on second page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying do display list of employees after search. It works find but I want to extend my code to display more details on second page after user cliks on the cell or the button next to it.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="" method="POST"><span><div id="result" class="span5"></div></span></table>    
</form><script language="javascript">
$('#search').click(function() {
$.get("index.php/find/findemp",{firstname : $('#fn').val(),lastname :     $('#ln').val(),dept : $('#dt').val() },function(data) {  //  ,jobtitle : $('#jt').val()
        var names = '<table class="table table-hover">';
        var x = 0;
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            if (index > 0) {x++, names;}

            names += "<tr class = x><td>"+element.firstName +"</td> "+"<td>"+ element.lastName+ "</td> <td>"+ element.department+"<td/> <td> "+ element.officeDay+"</td><td>"+element.AvStatus+"</td></tr>"+ "<br/>";
        });
        names+='';
        $('#result').html(names);
    },"json");
    return false;
});
```

My plan is to get the `x` as a identifier and display details on the second page.

I want to use this code altho I don't understand it well so I will appreciate some advice.

```
$(".X").click(function() {
var name = $(".name",this).html();});
```

Second page code:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
            <div >

                <div>First name:        <br /> <input value="<?php echo $name[1]; ?>" type=text id="fn" name='firstname'> </div>
                <div>Last name:        <br />  <input value="<?php echo $name[2]; ?>"type=text id="ln" name='lastname'> </div>
                <div>Department Name:  <br />  <input value="<?php echo $name[3]; ?>" type=text id="dt" name='dept'></div>
                <div>Current job Title: <br /> <input value="<?php echo $name[4]; ?>" type=text id="jt" name='jobtitle'> </div>
                <div>Birth Date:  <br />  <input value="<?php echo $name[5]; ?>" type=text id="dt" name='dept'></div>
                <div>Hire Date:  <br />  <input value="<?php echo $name[6]; ?>" type=text id="dt" name='dept'></div>
                <div>Gender:  <br />  <input value="<?php echo $name[7]; ?>" type=text id="dt" name='dept'></div>


                <br /><div><input value="Update" type="submit" id="update"></div>
```

Reset

Comment: Please format that code block to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was not easy however I work on it quite long and it works now:

```
$(document).on('click', '.x', function(e) {
    var emp_no = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-emp-no');

    window.location = 'index.php/find/display/' + emp_no;

});
```

I was also pushed to create another model file to get employees by id, later I just call them by
  `<?= $lecturer_data[0]['firstName'] ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You could start by fetching only empoyee's names and idnumber on the first page, then create a number of submit buttons next to each name that sends that id number to the next page which contains the code to fetch further details for that id number.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the code for you

```
$(".X").click(function() {
 var name = $(".name",this).html();
});
```

1. It looks for the elements that has the class `.X` and binds the click event.
2. When that particular element is clicked it selected the elements that has a class `.name` and retrieve the HTML. `jQuery( selector [, context ] )` [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)
3. Those HTML is saved in the `name` variable.

## From Docs

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function() {
  $(  "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
});
```

> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of
> this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional
> class.
>
> Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method,
> so $( "span", this ) is equivalent to $( this ).find( "span" ).

Comment: So I push the name variable to the next page? Does it work as a identifier? @Dasun

Comment: name contains the HTML you selected.

Comment: `$(".X").click(function() {
 var name = $(".name",this).html(index.php/display_results/);
});`  Is this correct to call the second page?

Comment: How do I call the second page than? @Dasun